# Omnikey 1021 installation help

Tags: drivers, 13.04, card-reader

I am a lorry driver and I have to download information from my digital tachograph card to my computer and email them to my boss. I have an Onikey 1024 Smatcard reader and I have downloaded, from LaunchPad, the `pcsc-omnikey_3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb` to my desktop.
This is where I get stuck because when I run Terminal and enter

```
 sudo dpkg -i pcsc-omnikey_3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I get the following results:

```
Selecting previously unselected package pcsc-omnikey.
(Reading database ... 371699 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking pcsc-omnikey (from pcsc-omnikey_3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pcsc-omnikey:
 pcsc-omnikey depends on pcscd; however:
  Package pcscd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing pcsc-omnikey (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pcsc-omnikey
```

I have searched for `pcscd` but aparently it has been removed from the LaunchPad disk...

Where should I go and what would I best do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install pcscd either in the Ubuntu Software Center or in the terminal. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install pcscd
cd ~/Desktop/ && sudo dpkg -i pcsc-omnikey_3-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```